# Access (private) members with dot separated String

Tags: java, reflection

Can I access to instance fields by the following syntax:
student.address.city

```
public class Student {
   private Address address;
   //getters&setters
}

public class Address {
    private String town;
    private String street;
    private String city;
   //getters&setters
}
```

I think it can be done somehow using reflection.
Basically I need something like:

```
String city = getPropertyValue("student.address.city", student);
```

Like in js we can access object properties.

Comment: make it easy, post some code......

Comment: thanks to **talex** and **Adowrath**. By using your answers the problem was solved.

Comment: There is also a method in org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty() dedicated for that .

Comment: @romanvintonyak if an answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tickmark to its left. If you found a different solution, please consider adding an answer of your own. Your comment above makes me suspect the former.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is also a method called org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty() dedicated for that .

Answer (score 3):

This is actually pretty straight forward using the getDeclaredField method.

But, supply the `student` at the beginning as a first parameter, as Java has no clue which `student-object` you are referencing.

```
void someOtherMethod() {
    // ...
    Student student = // ...
    String city = getPropertyValue(student, "address.city");
    // ...
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T getPropertyValue(Object obj, String string) {
    Object ret = obj;
    String[] parts = string.split("\\.");

    for(String field : parts) {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = ret.getClass();
            Field f = clazz.getDeclaredField(field);
            f.setAccessible(true);
            ret = f.get(ret);
        } catch(NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    return (T) ret;
}
```

Make the `#getPropertyValue` method `static` so you can reference it all the time from everywhere and even `import` it statically.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not support this syntax by default. But you can easily do it yourself.
First parse the `String` with which you want to access the properties.

```
 String[] path = "a.b.x".split("\\.");
```

Note: You need to escape the `.` character because [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) works with [`Regular Expressions`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), and `.` is treated as a special wildcard symbol in [`RegEx`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RegEx).

After that, you can use the parts in `path` to find the value like this:

```
Object o = ... // An Object to start with, "Student" in your 
               // example (don't make it Student o = ... though!)
for(String part : path){
    o = resolveField(o, part) // Overwrites with the new object
}
```

The final result is saved in `o`.

All the reflection happens in the method `resolveField`

```
Object resolveField(Object root, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> clazz = root.getClass();
    Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true); // Lets you work with private fields. You do not 
                               // have to restore the old value as it's only 
                               // for the Field object, not for the field itself
    return field.get(root);
}
```

Note that there are some libraries that contain this functionality already, e.g. the [Java Expressions Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/jel/manual.html), although it is much more than that.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, make your fields/properties `public` e.g.

```
public class Student {
    public Address address;

}

public class Address {
    public String town;
    public String street;
    public String city;

}
```

and get rid off your getters/setters

Comment: no, imagine that I have a string like "student.address.city"